# What is the historical reason for using curly braces {} as placeholder in find -exec

Tags: find, history, parameter

Everyone knows `find . -exec foo {} \;` and at some point stopped thinking about it. But recently I came back to the question that arose when I first learned it:

> Why would anyone choose `{}` as the placeholder for the path/name?

If you had to specify a syntax, you would maybe use some `$` combination like they are used for parameters of variables in a bunch of other languages. Of as a C programmer one could be tempted to use `%`like in `printf`. Even `@` would feel a natural choice. Or some "free" character without special meaning in that context. But why a pair of curly braces with nothing inside? Braces were always meant to collect something inside. This seems like the oddest idea to me.

I understand that most of the `find` history [seems to be lost in the uncertain](http://doc.cat-v.org/unix/find-history), but maybe someone has knowledge of some early tool using curly braces a similar way?

Comment: The text linked to refers to `find` in UNIX release 7, but the sources for `find` are available as early as [UNIX release 5](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/blob/Research-V5-Snapshot-Development/usr/source/s1/find.c) (1974?)

Comment: probably because very few things would normally use `{}` and, as you say, they imply a container....a container for the filename(s) that find will be inserting into that space.

Comment: `$` in particular would be bad, since it would get confused with shell variables and you'd need to escape it if the placeholder something else followed by the dollar. Though then again, `find` does use `;`, which needs to be escaped from the shell...

Comment: @ilkkachu I guess that's why it is a common concept in several tools to pass the whole command to be executed as one argument, for example by single quoting the whole command. Who would mind `find . -exec 'foo %; bar %'`?

Comment: @Philippos, anyone who wanted to run something more complex. Having the command in single string would require `find` to process some form of quoting (or require always forking a shell to do it). The way it currently works, `find` doesn't need to do that, the shell running `find` splits the `-exec` command to arguments and `find` just passes those on when starting the command.

Comment: @ilkkachu   e.g. anyone who wanted to run anything involving printf formatting strings via -exec.

Answer (score -1):

The possible reason could be to denote the endless possibilities which can be shunted after `find` and you would need some symbol in common which would just mean that convergence of the numerous possibilities. So `{}` denotes just that.

`man find` however does not have a mention of the reason.